# Excel Formula Showing "=#VALUE!"

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel I have a cell with formula ("=......"). On the cell, I can clearly see the value of the formula, but the formula bar shows "=#VALUE!". How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

highlight the cell and hit <kbd>F2</kbd> then edit it in place.

**Additional info:**
I also want to be clear that your formula isn't

```
("=...")
```

but instead is

```
="..."
```

For example,

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,"asdf")
```

is a good formula.

```
("=CONCATENATE(A1,"asdf"")
```

is not a good formula.

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is something wrong with the formula in the cell.  Perhaps there is a cell that you are trying to reference that is empty or there has the wrong datatype.

Comment: But if i click on that cell and hit "copy" and paste it on a notepad, the "result" is correct (my formula is just a string concatenation of various substrings" and other ranges)

Comment: can you provide an example that will trigger the exception case?

Comment: Even if my formula is wrong, what if i want to edit my formula? I can't even do that now, since the formula bar shows "=#VALUE!", and my formula is not "=VALUE!"

Comment: It's rather hard to tell if you don't provide an example here.

Answer (score 1):

Just double click on the cell and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.You will be able to see the values properly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something that only looks correct such as :

A1+A2+A3 - error
A5: =SUM(A1+A2+A3) - error

A6: =SUM(A1,A2,A3) - correct
A7: =SUM(A1:A3) - correct

Answer (score 0):

Possible that your formula requires a specific addon that is not installed - For example using `yearfrac()` in a system which doesn't have Analysis ToolPak (ATP) installed will cause throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

methinks... the cell size isnt that big enough to fit the value.. try increasing the  width